# Simulate holding down key in order to gauge system repeat rate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, simulation, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a pointless (read: makes the girlfriend happy) webpage that, every half second, spawns a unicorn image which hops across the screen.  You can also spawn them by pressing <kbd>u</kbd>.  I discovered after writing this script that the `onkeydown` event will repeat when held down--the `onkeyup` event does not, which was why I was surprised.  This "feature" was endearing to me, so now I want to replicate it for mobile browsers.

The goal is to create a `<div>` at the bottom of the screen, that when held down, spawns unicorns.  Obviously I could (and probably will) just use `setInterval()` with a static 33ms delay to mimic [Windows's default/max keyboard repeat speed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.keyboardspeed.aspx), but where's the fun in that?

But out of curiosity, I'm wondering if there's a way to mimic holding down a key, triggering the `keypress` or `keydown` events as the keyboard would for whatever device is running the page, so I can mimic holding down the key as exactly as possible while the user "holds down" the div.

I'm fine with using jQuery or any other framework like that.

Comment: `onkeypress` should repeat. `onkeydown` should not. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using Chrome, but apparently this is the expected behavior... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling

Answer (score 1):

Simulating the auto-repeat feature is not possible in javascript without manually coding the setInterval. That happens at the operating system level.

Simulating a single keyboard event is possible. You're looking for `element.dispatchEvent(evt);`

```
//create your fake event
var myFakeEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', []);
//send the event from the element
document.body.dispatchEvent(myFakeEvent);
```

Obviously, you want to call dispatchEvent() from whatever element the onkeydown is listening to.

More detailed reading:

[EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

[KeyboardEvent constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Yet there's no way of simulating "holding the key" other than dispatching these events from a `setInterval`

Comment: Oh. Yeah, no. You have to do it with an interval. The repetitive firing of the key being pressed happens on the operating system level.

Comment: @cutmancometh could you add that comment to an answer so I can accept it?